# How do I set a property to a file on the svn directory using the sharpsvn clinet class?

Tags: c#, properties, sharpsvn

I am using the Sharpsvn client class to set a property on a file in a svn directory. I want to continually reset the property with a new timestamp and in doing that a new revision with a new log message will update in the Repository history. The thing I don't want to do is make a change to the file then commit it back to the directory.  Right now, I am stuck with trying to figure out how to connect to the file on the directory. Here is the code I currently have:

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("url link");

using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
  try
  {
    // Get new timestamp
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    string time = String.Format("{0:G}", dt);

    // Set property to file in the svn directory
    client.RemoteSetProperty(uri, "svn:time", time);
  }
  catch (Svnexception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.show(ex.Message + "Check out error!");
  }
}
```

I tried using the client.SetProperty method as well, but that didn't work when I tried it on both a local working copy and straight to the url. Help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Altered some parts of your code to make it work as required. Please take a look:

```
                System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("url link");

                using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Get new timestamp
                        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                        string time = String.Format("{0:G}", date);

                        // To Get the Latest Revision on the Required SVN Folder
                        SvnInfoEventArgs info;
                        client.GetInfo(uri, out info);

                        // Prepare a PropertyArgs object with latest revision and a commit message;
                        SvnSetPropertyArgs args = new SvnSetPropertyArgs() { BaseRevision = info.Revision, LogMessage = "Sample msg for SVN commit" };

                        // Set property to file in the svn directory
                        client.RemoteSetProperty(uri, "svn:time", time, args);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Check out error!");
                    }
                }
```

Hope this helps;